# SQL Syntax error. Suddenly broke?

Tags: mysql

When trying to create this table, it doesn't want to work properly though it worked minutes before? Assume that `$username` is equal to `"Test"` for brevity.

The error I'm receiving is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '( id(10) INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id), message
>   varchar(250), ' at line 2

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$username}
(
id(10) INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),
message varchar(250),
sender varchar(100)
)";
```

Comment: Is the username *actually* "Test"?  You aren't enclosing it with backticks, so there's a danger of colliding with a reserved keyword.

Comment: Does $username have unescaped apostrophes in?

Comment: Did you create the table one time, with no error. Then you try to create it again? I guess table already exists?

Comment: I used mysql_real_escape_string and I tried stripslashes in php

Answer (score 2):

You have a SQL syntax error.

Instead of `id(10) INT AUTO_INCREMENT` 
It should be `id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT`